# How to set a default value from a SQLAlchemy relationship?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a set of classes defined like this:

```
class CrosstabCohort(Base):
    __table__ = crosstab_cohorts
    # has property is_column
    cohort = relationship(Cohort, innerjoin=True)

class Crosstab(Base):
    __table__ = crosstabs

    columns = relationship(CrosstabCohort,
            #secondary=crosstab_cohorts,
            primaryjoin=and_(
                crosstabs.c.crosstab_id == crosstab_cohorts.c.crosstab_id,
                crosstab_cohorts.c.is_column == True),
            order_by=crosstab_cohorts.c.created_at,
            )

    rows = relationship(CrosstabCohort,
            #secondary=crosstab_cohorts,
            primaryjoin=and_(
                crosstabs.c.crosstab_id == crosstab_cohorts.c.crosstab_id,
                crosstab_cohorts.c.is_column == False),
            order_by=crosstab_cohorts.c.created_at,
            )
```

When I add column or row objects by calling `append` on the relationship instance, I'd like for the `is_column` property to be automatically set to either `True` or `False` depending upon which relationship I append it to. Is this possible? At present, when I append to these relationships and try to commit, I receive an error from my database that the `is_column` property is not set. Can this be done automatically or must I set the `is_column` property on each `Cohort` object?